# Xcode targets with GIT

Tags: ios, xcode, git, target

Today I created a new target in my iOS app to make a rebrand of the app.

Now I see in Git that it shows some files from the original target(.pbxproj, .xcsheme, .plist) as missing, but that is supposed to happen (I assume).

My question is, what do I do with these files?
Just commit them as missing or is it better to set the files to ignore?
Currently I am working alone on this project but that might change in the future.

Thanks

Comment: I think all those files should be tracked by git, but some others need ignoring (via the early use of `.gitignore`). You need to do a search for "gitignore for Xcode".

Comment: @trojanfoe So if I understand it correctly, you think I should commit these missing files (basically deleting them from origin)

Comment: Creating a new target in a project should **not** cause any existing files to be “missing”.

Comment: All I did was make a duplicate of the existing target and edited some things like provisioning profiles, is there something I am doing wrong then?

Comment: Ah I figured out what I did wrong, I accidentally renamed  the project instead of something in the target causing the files to be renamed and therefore missing in GIT's eyes